# Php, DI, references doesnt work as expected

Tags: php, reference

a simple example:

```
class A
{
    /**
     * @var Injected
     */
    private $injected;

    public function __construct(Injected $injected)
    {
        $this->injected = $injected;
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $this->injected->e();
    }
}

class B
{
    /**
     * @var Injected
     */
    private $injected;

    public function __construct(Injected $injected)
    {
        $this->injected = $injected;
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $this->injected->e();
    }
}

class Injected
{
    private $a;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->a = mt_rand(1,9999999999);
        echo 'Generated: '.$this->a.'<br>';
    }
    public function e()
    {
        echo $this->a.'<br>';
    }
}

$o = new Injected();
$a = new A($o);
$b = new B($o);
$a->get();
$b->get();
$o = new Injected();
$a->get();
$b->get();
```

and when I run:

```
Generated: 1223710791
1223710791
1223710791
Generated: 1135116298
1223710791
1223710791
```

its not precisely what I expected. The first three 1223710791 is correct - but the last two seems to be failed. I wanted to get this!

```
Generated: 1223710791
1223710791
1223710791
Generated: 1135116298
1135116298
1135116298
```

it looks like even I replace the reference of `$o` it wont change in the `A` and `B` classes. Why? If they were normal variables, it would be understandable, but they are object and so references! I didnt even cloned them... that way there is no way to change `$injected`, apart from setters (which not an option this time)

Comment: `$o` is a normal variable, not a reference. So I guess, this answers your question?

Comment: @hakre: kind of, but... then how to make it reference?

Comment: By using the `&` operator / language construct. But: Are you really sure you need that? If you make `$o->e()` return something different, you have it solved as well w/o any reference, just sharing the instance. Correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have that (strange, and potentially unpredictable) behavior by replacing the constructor of your `A`/`B` classes:

```
public function __construct(Injected &$injected)
{
    $this->injected = &$injected;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but isnt it deprecated? I meant the & operator

Comment: No. I guess you're confusing with `$obj  =& new Obj` - that's deprecated

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's `static` features for this. You could say they work almost like references, I don't know all the details under the hood but the following will work as you expected.

You need to change some of `Injected`'s code to static and leave the others untouched:

```
class A
{
    /**
     * @var Injected
     */
    private $injected;

    public function __construct(Injected $injected)
    {
        $this->injected = $injected;
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $this->injected->e();
    }
}

class B
{
    /**
     * @var Injected
     */
    private $injected;

    public function __construct(Injected $injected)
    {
        $this->injected = $injected;
    }

    public function get()
    {
        $this->injected->e();
    }
}

class Injected
{
    private static $a;
    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$a = mt_rand(1,9999999999);
        echo 'Generated: '.self::$a.'<br>';
    }
    public function e()
    {
        echo self::$a.'<br>';
    }
}

$o = new Injected();
$a = new A($o);
$b = new B($o);
$a->get();
$b->get();
$o = new Injected();
$a->get();
$b->get();
```

Result:

```
Generated: 5231916164
5231916164
5231916164
Generated: 166525017
166525017
166525017
```

Comment: You just suggested to use a global variable - that is what static is for, but mixing the ctor with the static member feels so wrong I needed to press the downvote button. sorry, but this is dangerously convoluted.

Comment: @hakre not worries. If you have a better solution that works as the OP wants I suggest you post it.